# Hebrew font size on Chrome search bar looks weird, some letters are smaller than others

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

Something strange is going on with my friend's Chrome search bar, and only with Hebrew letters (as opposed to English letters) - some of the letters look smaller than others:

[image]

For comparison, this is how it looks on my own pc:

[image]

My friend Chrome version is 86.0.4240.193, on Windows 7.
My Chrome version is 86.0.4240.183, but on Windows 10.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to uninstall and re-install Chrome (saving bookmarks).

Comment: You could download an old version of Chrome and install it. Before installation, you will remove a current version of chrome. And then update the old version after the installation to see if the issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome didn't solve it. Downgrading to older version solved it, but not without a bit of struggle: I first tried to downgrade to Chrome 85, than 84, than 83, but each time got an error when trying to install. Apparently, a Windows restart was needed, and after doing it - installation worked (I finally went with Chrome 80).